# Is there any process to get the data directly from Cassandra to Aerospike?

Tags: cassandra, aerospike

Is there any process to get the data directly from Cassandra to Aerospike (without CSV file dump)?.

Comment: I would imagine a spark job being the most efficient / performant mechanism, but that would be pretty custom, and not a generic tool. The question borders on asking for a tool recommendation, which is not considered particularly on-topic.

Answer (score 2):

I second the use of Spark.  You can build jobs to pull from each of your tables and work to parallelize your extraction and load, using the Spark framework and scalability patterns to your benefit.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).